# How to write a unit test for MongoDB query built with queryBuilder in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am struggling to understand how to write unit test for this piece of code

```
$qb = $documentManager->getRepository('Document:Account')->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->remove(\project\Document\Account::class)->field('username')
   ->equals($userAccount->getUsername())->getQuery()->execute();
```

Here is my attempt to mock this part

```
$account = new account();
$documentAccount = $this->createMock(documentAccount::class);
$this->dm->expects($this->any())->method('getRepository')
     ->with($documentAccount)
     ->willReturn($account);
```

but I keep getting this error when the control reaches this part.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

PHP unit: *PHPUnit 8.5.21*

PHP: *PHP 7.2.34*

Symfony: *Symfony 4.4.18*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it,. it might be helpful to someone struggling with similar issue

```
$accountDocumentRepo = $this->getMockBuilder(\project\Document\Account::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->disableOriginalClone()
            ->disableArgumentCloning()
            ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
            ->setMethods(['remove','createQueryBuilder','field','equals','getQuery', 'execute'])
            ->getMock();

        $this->tradeDm->expects(self::any())->method('getRepository')->willReturn($accountDocumentRepo);

        $accountDocumentRepo->method('createQueryBuilder')->willReturn($accountDocumentRepo);
        $accountDocumentRepo->method('remove')->willReturn($accountDocumentRepo);
        $accountDocumentRepo->method('equals')->willReturn($accountDocumentRepo);
        $accountDocumentRepo->method('field')->willReturn($accountDocumentRepo);
        $accountDocumentRepo->method('getQuery')->willReturn($accountDocumentRepo);
        $accountDocumentRepo->method('execute')->willReturn($accountDocumentRepo);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you needed to mock all method called.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you don't mock from `$documentManager`, your test case must start from it apparently.

I used to test with `Prophecy` but with native `MockBuilder` it's same logic.
Consider I don't know real class your use case is using so I give you an idea of approximately what you have to do, take a look at code below:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->createMock(QueryBuilder::class);
    $documentManager = $this->createMock(DocumentMannager::class);
    $documentAccount = $this->createMock(Document::Account);
    
    $documentManager
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->with('Document:Account')
        ->willReturn($documentAccount)
    ;

    $documentAccount
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('createQueryBuilder')
        ->willReturn($queryBuilder)
    ;
    
    $queryBuilder
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('remove')
        ->with(\project\Document\Account::class)
        ->willReturn($queryBuilder)
    ;
    
    $queryBuilder
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('field')
        ->with('username')
        ->willReturn($queryBuilder)
    ;
    
    $queryBuilder
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('equals')
        ->withAnyParameters()
        ->willReturn($queryBuilder)
    ;
    
    $queryBuilder
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getQuery')
        ->willReturn($queryBuilder)
    ;
    
    
    $queryBuilder
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('execute')
    ;
```

We exactly mock each call of original code

```
$qb = $documentManager->getRepository('Document:Account')->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->remove(\project\Document\Account::class)->field('username')
   ->equals($userAccount->getUsername())->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention `$documentManager` is passed to test as `$this->dm`

Comment: You haven't used `$documentManager` anywhere after declaring. 
Secondly, do you mean `$queryBuilder = $this->createMock(documentAccount::class);` ? when you say `$queryBuilder = $this->createMock(QueryBuilder::class);` documentAccount is `Document:Account`
Thanks

Comment: I edit solution because i forgot mock for `$documentManager,` for method `->createQueryBuilder()` you have to inspect what is the real class for etablish the corresponding mock and I don't think it's `documentAccount`, don't forget it's a proposal because i don't know you whole code.